# Checking if a row exists in a SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to search a database to see if a row exists. I have found the following code in another Stackoverflow post:

```
public static boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName,
        String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + " = " + fieldValue;
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

My database consists of three columns `id` an integer primary key, `title` as text, and `episodes` as text. The database is created successfully and I am able to store and retrieve entries but when I implemented the code above, my program would crash telling me that no column name exists for `fieldValue`.

I am calling the method with my table name as `TableName`, and the column name as `dbfield`, and the entry I am looking for as `fieldValue`.

Doing so would throw an exception saying that the `fieldValue` Column does not exist. Am I understanding this wrong? The `fieldValue` would be a string entry in one of the columns that I am searching for in my database right?

Comment: For the people downvoting, could I get an explanation why? I just wanted clarification to an answer that was posted in another stackoverflow post...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` query as this returns just a 1x1 cursor with a single integer value.

```
public static boolean valueExistsInDb(String table, String field, String value) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + table + " WHERE " + field + " = ?";
    String[] sqlArgs = new String[]{ value };
    Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(sql, sqlArgs);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            return cursor.getInt(0) > 0;
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Right...there's at least two things wrong with this.

1. **This code is vulnerable to a SQL injection.**  You could receive any string value and you would execute it.  This *includes* someone being able to drop your database tables.  You *never* want to use string interpolation; look into Android's equivalent of prepared statements.  Always use a concrete table name and prefer concrete column names.
2. Checking if a specific value exists in a database is a simple `EXISTS` query.  You'd rewrite it like this:

   ```
   String query = "select exists(select * from concreteTableName where concreteField = ?)"
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about SQL injection, I have already replaced the Strings. As for the query you gave me, would I replace the `?` with the value that I am searching for?

Comment: Again - look into Android's equivalent of a `PreparedStatement`.  The idea is that the markers would be position-substituted with the value you are searching for later on.

Comment: After doing some searches, I found `SQLiteStatement` with the `bindString` method. Would this be the way to go?